# Can't get panels and buttons to display across methods

Tags: java, constructor, jframe, jpanel, actionlistener

I'm working on a calculator/phone input keypad, and am having all sorts of trouble getting it to actually display the buttons. I got it to work when everything was in the main method, but that wouldn't allow me to implement ActionListener, which I need in order for the buttons to work. Here's the code I have right now:

```
import java.awt.*; //Import everything
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*; //Seriously, everything, just makes this easier

public class Keypad extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Create the frame that holds everything else
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Almost Functional Keypad");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Create the keypad
    frame.getContentPane().add(new Keypad());

    //Stuff to do so it won't break
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,400));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
}

public Keypad(){
    //Create the array of JPanels and labels
    JButton[] keyList = new JButton[12];
    JLabel[] keyLabel = new JLabel[12];

    //Array with the key labels
    String[] keyLabelText = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","*","0","#"};

    //We need a counter
    int i;

    //Create the panels
    for (i=0; i<12; i++){
        keyList[i]= new JButton();
        keyList[i].setPreferredSize (new Dimension(100, 75));
        keyLabel[i] = new JLabel (keyLabelText[i]);
        keyList[i].add (keyLabel[i]);
        keyList[i].addActionListener(this);
    }

    //Text field that only the buttons can modify
    JTextArea displayText = new JTextArea();
    displayText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 20));

    //Create the "clear" button
    JButton clear = new JButton();
    clear.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 40));
    JLabel clearLabel = new JLabel ("Clear");
    clear.add(clearLabel);
    clear.addActionListener(this);

    // Set up primary panel
    JPanel primary = new JPanel();
    primary.add(displayText);
    for (i=0; i<12; i++){
        primary.add (keyList[i]);
    }
    primary.add(clear);
}

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){
        //Stuff goes here eventually
}


}
```

I'm pretty sure that it has something to do with calling Keypad() in main, but I have no idea how to call it and get things to display. I have to create the panels in the constructor, otherwise I can't add ActionListener, but now I don't know how to get them into frame.

Thanks for any help, and I'm hoping it's just something small and stupid I'm forgetting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes i made to your code were changing the constructor to a method returning a JPanel and some very minor changes. You should notice that now the function returns a JPanel which fixes your problem.

Check this

```
import java.awt.*; //Import everything
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*; //Seriously, everything, just makes this easier

public class Keypad extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

public static void main(String[] args) {
//Create the frame that holds everything else
JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Almost Functional Keypad");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

//Create the keypad
frame.getContentPane().add(getKeypad());

//Stuff to do so it won't break
frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,400));
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setResizable(false);
}

public static JPanel getKeypad(){
//Create the array of JPanels and labels

Keypad obj = new Keypad();
JButton[] keyList = new JButton[12];
JLabel[] keyLabel = new JLabel[12];

//Array with the key labels
String[] keyLabelText = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","*","0","#"};

//We need a counter
int i;

//Create the panels
for (i=0; i<12; i++){
    keyList[i]= new JButton();
    keyList[i].setPreferredSize (new Dimension(100, 75));
    keyLabel[i] = new JLabel (keyLabelText[i]);
    keyList[i].add (keyLabel[i]);
    keyList[i].addActionListener(obj);
}

//Text field that only the buttons can modify
JTextArea displayText = new JTextArea();
displayText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 20));

//Create the "clear" button
JButton clear = new JButton();
clear.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 40));
JLabel clearLabel = new JLabel ("Clear");
clear.add(clearLabel);
clear.addActionListener(obj);

// Set up primary panel
JPanel primary = new JPanel();
primary.add(displayText);
for (i=0; i<12; i++){
    primary.add (keyList[i]);
}
primary.add(clear);
return primary;
}

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){
    //Stuff goes here eventually
    // use it like this
    //if(event.getSource()==whateveryouwanttotest){
    //
    //}
}
}
```

Comment: That fixed it. I'm going to need to make a note of returning it - not sure why I didn't think of that before. Also completely missed the idea of using "obj" as a placeholder instead of "this". I had to modify some of the code slightly (dimensions were wrong, probably my mistake), but other than that, this works pretty much perfectly.

This is beyond the scope of the question, but I think switch might be better than if for the keys, I'll have to test it out.

Comment: Of course, that was just to show you how to use the function "getSource()"